# Loop through files with .jar extension [Batch]

Tags: batch-file

So, I've got a bit of code, which would in theory work, but it doesn't..
It loops through some files, but not all, but not the specific file type I want it to loop through (.jar)

I got:

```
for /r %%f in (*.jar) do (
    ECHO path=%%~pf
    ECHO filename=%%~nf
    ECHO fileextension=%%~xf
    SET fileextension=%%~xi
    IF "%fileextension%" == ".jar" (
        call proc %%f
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
IF "%fileextension%" == ".jar" (
```

to

```
IF /i "%%~xf" == ".jar" (
```

Three problems:

1) the filename is in `%%f`, not `%%i`

2) Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`.

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, `REM` statements rather than the broken-label remark form (`:: comment`) should be used because labels terminate blocks, confusing `cmd`.

Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered.

Two common ways to overcome this are 1) to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `!var!` in place of `%var%` to access the changed value of `var` or 2) to call a subroutine to perform further processing using the changed values.

2) you'd probably need `if /i` to make the `if` statement case-insensitive, for the situation where the file extension matches but is a different case.

Comment: Didn't work, but I just quickly programmed a java Class to execute the commands for me. Ezpz xP Thanks anyways! <3